# All groups in same parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this kind of markup

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="divider"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
</div>
```

And I want all elements of class `to-be-wrapped` that are next to each other to be wrapped in another div so output would be:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="divider"></div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
    <div class="to-be-wrapped"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When I use `.wrapAll` method of **jQuery** on `.to-be-wrapped`, then they are wrapped together in one only new wrapper.

Is there some jQuery method or other way to do that?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A4RAy/)

Comment: This is also a way to accomplish your task. http://jsfiddle.net/A4RAy/2/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of way of doing it:

```
var $c = $('.container');

while ($c.children('.to-be-wrapped').length)
    $c.children('.to-be-wrapped:first')
      .nextUntil('.divider')
      .addBack()
      .wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"/>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/A4RAy/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$(".divider:first").prevAll(".to-be-wrapped").wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'/>");
$(".divider").each(function(){
  $(this).nextAll(".to-be-wrapped").wrapAll("<div class='wrapper'/>");
```

});